# Improve SSO experience for companies internal staff while accessing consumer application protected by Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have a consumer facing application (call it consumer.com) whose user identities is managed via. Azure AD B2C.  This consumer.com app has admin screens which is accessed by the internal staff whose identity is managed by Azure AD.  To enable SSO experience for the internal staff the organizations Azure AD is registered as Custom Identity provider in B2C tenant.  This allows the internal staff to use the corporate Azure AD credentials to login to the consumer.com application by clicking on the appropriate 'External identities' button.  In this flow if the internal user has already authenticated to Office365 then clicking on the 'External identities' button will automatically authenticate user.  I was wondering if the experience can be improved by cutting short the need for internal user to click on the button, perhaps the user session that exist in the browser can be used to bring in this experience.  How to achieve this?

I am also looking for a solution where user will click on a link (Consumer app button) within one of Office365 apps which would then redirect to consumer.com application, of course the expectation here is to directly authenticate without needing to go through B2c login page.  If this can be achieved, what information should the url link contain?

Answer (score 0):

Use the domain hint parameter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin#redirect-sign-in-to-a-social-provider